# Reading and understanding a raw audio file(specifically MP3)

Tags: audio, mp3

I am trying to understand what the raw data from an audio file looks like and how to get that data. I want to take the data and analyze it and see if I am able to make a program that can recognize patterns in a song such as in a hip hop song, finding the same beat in a chorus. In my head I think this could be a doable task if the data is in an integer form.

I've looked up many tutorials for this but all the tutorials use other libraries or don't explain it in a way I understand(more than likely the source of my issue).

I am wondering if there is someone out there that can help me understand a few things.

1). In an MP3 file, what is actually being stored in the file. Is it an integer that tells the radio/amp/audioPlayer a frequency, another integer for amplitude, etc...(over simplified because I don't know what other data is stored in an audio file).

2). If it is stored in an integer format, is there a way to read the integers and analyze it. If it is not stored in an integer format, how is it stored, and is there a way to convert it to an integer format?

3). In visual representations of an audio files like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_MtTedqOvA) one, it seems more clear what is what. It seems like the frequency is where on the circle the audio is represented, and the amplitude is how high it jumps. Is this right? Or does it just appear that way and I am understanding it incorrectly.

4). Is this task harder than I think it is? Considering I haven't found any good explanations or tutorials on how to do so, I am skeptical on how easy this would be.

(Sorry if this was poorly phrased, first question on stack and I am just illiterate :^)

Comment: I'd recommend you read the standards for MP3 to understand what is stored.  I can tell you now that it's not stored using simple integer format, and uses lots of matrices and linear algebra, so you may be in a bit over your head.  The standard for MP3 is defined in ISO11172-3 and ISO13818-3.  This is going to be a very difficult task, but I wish you luck!

Comment: Compressed audio formats such as MP3 or FLAC use very complex representations of the audo in order to achieve the compression. An uncompressed format such as WAV would be a simpler place to start.

Comment: I understand the file structure of an mp3 file. There's a header that contains data about the file along with bitrate, frequency, version and layer of the file along with some other attributes that I am not sure have any significance in an mp3 file. Regardless, everywhere I read says that mp3 files contain the music data after the header, such as [this](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/images/e/ee/Mp3filestructure.jpg) diagram. It also shows different ways of showing the data such as bits, binary, and hex. I am not sure why there's three different representations. Any help on clarifying?

Comment: Imagine trying to open a text file that is zipped and trying to make sense of data that is still in the zipped form. What you are attempting is even more difficult. Software that does any analysis of frequencies or rhythms first unpacks the compressed data to a PCM format (Pulse Code Modulation). The most usual thing is to work with a data file where the wave is described via data points (usually floats, sometimes doubles) that range between -1 and 1. Another common PCM form is integers between -32767 and 32767 (coded in 16 bits). Until the mp3 is decoded, what you will find is gobblygook.